# Usage of "the" before a verbal noun

Tags: grammar

Should I use **the** before the **verbal noun** in the following sentence?

Here is the sentence:

> John, you should come at 11 A.M before **(the)** beginning of the game.

I know I can write "John, you should come at 11 am before the game begins."  My question is, in this kind of context, should I need to use **the**?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should, since 'beginning' here, as you note, is a (verbalised) noun or a Gerund. 
Here you could substitute 'beginning' with the noun 'start': the start of the game.

The usage will follow the general usage of the article with nouns. (Here you are talking about a specific game with a specific beginning so it takes the definite article 'the'.)